# Why does mitochondrial DNA have a high mutation rate, even though the mitochondrial function is highly conserved?

Tags: molecular-genetics, mutations, molecular-evolution, mitochondria

My understanding is that genes that are functionally important are more highly conserved. The DNA coding for ribosomal RNA is one example of that. I was surprised to find out that mitochondrial DNA had a high mutation rate. I'm mostly concerned with metazoan mitochondrial DNA, and more specifically, animal or mammalian mitochondrial DNA.

I've tried searching why exactly that is, and so far, from what I understand, it could be:

- the lack of DNA repair enzymes in the mitochondria
- the production of free radicals in the oxidative phosphorylation process leading to more point mutations

But how would the cell with these somatic mutations (or embryo with inherited germ line mutations) survive then? Are these mutations only passed down in the non-coding regions on the mtDNA, and the coding regions are indeed highly conserved?

I've also read that:

- the high mutation rate refers more to the shifts in gene order on the chromosome
- critical genes in the mitochondria migrate to nuclear DNA

I think I could be missing some understanding of wobble base pairing in the  mitochondrial translation system, or some quirks of the bacterial DNA, etc. I've hoping for a relatively complex and in-depth explanation of this. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please give a source for your statement about the rate of mutation in mitochondrial DNA. Also your assumption about importance and conservation — cytochrome c comes to mind as a counter example.

Comment: This is one example: Sen Xu, Sarah Schaack, Amanda Seyfert, Eunjin Choi, Michael Lynch, Melania E. Cristescu, High Mutation Rates in the Mitochondrial Genomes of Daphnia pulex, Molecular Biology and Evolution, Volume 29, Issue 2, February 2012, Pages 763–769, https://doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msr243

I would be happy to learn about why that assumption is wrong for cytochrome c as well. I'm looking in general to understand why mutation rates can be high for a highly conserved structure.

Comment: I'd put the reference in your question. Be careful. Your question referred to highly conserved function, not structure. Cytochrome c is a protein whose function is conserved through many species, but large sequence variation has occured, outwith the residues crucial for function.